# Как в c# скопировать 1gb файл в память и найти в нем нужную строку максимально быстро?

Tags: c#, поиск

Как в c# скопировать 1gb файл в память и найти в нем нужную строку максимально быстро?

Comment: Считать файл в String и сделать поиск по строке. Или считать в массив String.

Comment: это долго читать, нужен более быстрый метод

Comment: >это долго читать, нужен более быстрый метод

долго это сколько? И сколько должно быть, чтобы было быстро? В конце концов изобретите новый вид жестких дисков, которые способны считывать информацию быстрее, чем ныне существующие. Скорость выполнения вашей задачи напрямую упирается в возможности современных накопителей, и C# тут ни при чем.

Comment: как вы предлагаете максимально быстро считать файл 1гб в стринг?

Comment: @prog432 я еще раз хотел бы спросить - "быстро", "максимально быстро" и прочие неопределенные эпитеты, употребляемые вами - это сколько в секундах? Более того, ничего читать в string я не предлагал. Не уверен, что это хорошая затея. Я даже не знаю, о каком файле идет речь. Если это не текстовый, а некий бинарный файл, то читать его в string затея еще более сомнительная

Comment: файл текстовый, построчный поиск и чтение, сейчас построчный поиск с memory диска даёт 30 секунд на поиск, если читать буду напрямую в память в c# или искать при чтении - это ускорить по вашему мнению?

Comment: скорее всего если вы поместите содержимое файла в память целиком, то это сможет дать прирост производительности в поиске (затрудняюсь сказать, какой именно, поскольку с текстовыми файлами такого объема не работал). Сильно сомневаюсь, что его целесообразно запихивать в string, для этого существуют иные средства (особенно учитывая неизменяемость строк в .NET). Посмотрите в сторону всяческих StreamReader'ов и MemoryMappedFile

Answer (score 4):

Файл не обязательно читать в память. Можно перебирать построчно:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\data\episodes.txt"))
{
    if (line.Contains("episode") & line.Contains("2006"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

То же, но с использованием Linq:

```
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\data\episodes.txt")
                         .Where(x=>x.Contains("episode") & x.Contains("2006")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

Comment: а это http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx не быстрее будет в итоге?

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже подсказывали, не понятно, что точно вам нужно искать.

Если нужно произвести разовый поиск, то быстрее чем "читать и сразу анализировать данные" не получится. Тут все упирается в скорость чтения и анализа данных. Если вы уверены, что у вас тормоза на уровне чтения - копайте в чтение данных из файла. По байтам читать долго. Обычно рекомендуется читать данные из файла блоками по "размер страницы на жестком диске" меньше или равно буферу. т.е. если у вас NTFS система и размер страницы 4кбайта, то нужно выбрать размер буфера 4 или 8 или 16, т.е. кратное двум размеру страницы. Сильно много с запасом выбирать нет смысла. Достаточно равное или в два раза больше. Выигрыша не получите, считывая махом 2 мегабайта, за место 8 килобайт.

Если упирается в скорость анализа полученных данных - то тут смотрите логику саму, из вопроса не ясно, что вы ищите, как вы ищите...

Пример кода не помешал бы, чтобы можно было бы понять. На том же bat или powerhell делается это через потоковый анализ (как и в командной строке линукса), и прекрасно находятся данные. Вполне поставленную задачу можно решить одной строчкой кода, но нужно больше информации.